# Java library for graphical diff

Tags: java

Is there any Java library that can diff text (in particular XML) files and provide the result as an image (e.g. like Pretty Diff)?

Comment: There should be something useful here:
http://www.manageability.org/blog/stuff/open-source-xml-diff-in-java

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool called guiffy that provides an [API for diff and merge](http://www.guiffy.com/help/GuiffyHelp/Inside.html) in java - it is actually more than that as it provides Eclipse and Netbeans plugins and that's how I know about it.

It has a feature where the diff output can be saved as an HTML - you can use the HTML output instead of image and render it on a `JTextPane`

Answer (score 0):

JMeld 
http://keeskuip.home.xs4all.nl/jmeld/

can be nicely integrated in Swing Applications. It's not been updated since 2009 but still working. A newer fork of it is available at

https://github.com/albfan/jmeld